# Why is the second-order correlation function proportional to the population of the excited state?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, optics, photons, quantum-optics, photon-emission

In this paper (click to open it) [A. Beveratos et al., 'Bunching and antibunching from single NV color centers in diamond'](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0010044) the authors write the following equation (page 4, eq. 1.2):

[image]

Namely, they write Glauber's second-order correlation function as being proportional to the dynamic population of the excited state. However, they do not provide an explanation or an intuition.
How is it possible to prove the above equality?

Answer (score 1):

By definition, $g^{(2)}(\tau)=\frac{\langle I(t)I(t+\tau)\rangle}{\langle I(t)\rangle^2}$.

Assuming a stationary process, everything is invariant in time, one has
\begin{align}\langle I(t)I(t+\tau)\rangle&=\langle I(0)\cdot I(\tau)\rangle 
\\&= \Pr(\text{photon emitted at $t=0$}) \cdot \Pr(\text{photon emitted at $t=\tau$}|\text{photon emitted at $t=0$})\\
&=\langle I(t)\rangle \cdot k_{21}\sigma_2(\tau),\end{align}
where the population $\sigma_2(\tau)$ is computed assuming $\sigma_2(0)=1$,
which is a necessary condition for having a photon emitted at $t=0$ : If a photon was emitted, the NV center was in the excited state just before.

Furthermore, the average intensity is given by the spontaneous emission rate $k_{21}$ multiplied by the average population of the excited level $\langle \sigma_2(t)\rangle$. Assuming again a stationary process, we have then
$$\langle I(t)\rangle = k_{21} \langle \sigma_2(t)\rangle = k_{21} \sigma_2(\infty)$$ .

Putting everything together, we have
\begin{align}
g^{(2)}(\tau)&=\frac{\langle I(t)I(t+\tau)\rangle}{\langle I(t)\rangle^2}\\
  &=\frac{\langle I(t)\rangle \cdot k_{21}\sigma_2(\tau)}{\langle I(t)\rangle^2}\\
  &=\frac{k_{21}\sigma_2(\tau)}{\langle I(t)\rangle}\\
  &=\frac{k_{21}\sigma_2(\tau)}{k_{21}\sigma_2(\infty)}\\
  &=\frac{\sigma_2(\tau)}{\sigma_2(\infty)}
\end{align}
Q.E.D.

Comment: Thank you. Something is still a bit unclear to me. To me, $k_{21}\sigma_2(\tau)$ seems the probability to emit a photon, not the conditional probability to emit a photon with lag time $\tau$ after another photon was emitted at $t=0$. Could you please elaborate? Furthermore, why the average $\langle \sigma_2 \rangle$ should be identical to the asymptotic value $\sigma_2(\infty)$? This is not true in general for every function. Lastly, is it then correct to say that the above model is valid only with CW excitation? How would someone write an equivalent model for pulsed excitation?

Comment: 1. In the paper, they say that $\sigma_1(0)=1$, which only makes sense if a photon has been emitted at $t=0$.

Comment: 2. In the paper, they assume cw excitation, and implicitely the ergodic hypothesis. Furthermore, it is easy to see that, for any function, if $\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}f(x)$ is edifned, it is equal to $\lim_{T\rightarrow+\infty}\int{0}{T}\frac{f(t)}{T}dt$

Comment: 3. I was in the group publishing this at that time (but on another subject) and I remember Alexios wondering how to properly define this for pulsed excitation... The problem has likely be solved, but I don’t know how

Comment: 1. Maybe I am naive, but I still don't fully understand. Why does $\sigma_1(0) = 1$ imply that a photon has just been emitted? Couldn't it be interpreted as the NV center not having been excited and the photon being emitted much before? To me, $\sigma_1(0) = 1$ seems a necessary condition but not a sufficient condition.

Comment: All this work is done in the cw regime, where the illumination has started «a long time ago». In this case, since there is a continuous process punping the centers aways for level 1, the only possibibility to have $\sigma_1 = 1$ is for the center to have just arrived in this level

Comment: I see, but even with a continuous pumping process, the re-excitation should not be instantaneous but should happen on the time scale of $k_{12}^{-1}$. Is also in the model the assumption of large pump power and thus of diverging $k_{12}$?

Comment: It’s $σ_1(1)=0$, the population of the *ground* state. The reexcitation indeed increases (slowly) $σ_2(t)≃k_{12}t$ , with $\sigma_2(0)=0$